# Writing a dict to a file with a certain format

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, formatting, output

If I wanted to write a dict to a file with a specific format for each line what would be the best way to do this?

Currently I am doing:

```
    with open('filename', 'w') as j:
        print(dct, file = j)
```

But my output is, as you would expect:

```
    {<key>: <value>, <key>: <value>, <key>: <value>}
```

Is there a simple way to format the output so it reads that same dict as:

```
    <key> <value>
    <key> <value>
    <key> <value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
def write_dict(out_dict, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for key, value in out_dict.items():
            f.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: you shouldn't, they're all builtins. But you do need to make sure the file can actually be opened (I.E. python's ``open`` will not actually create missing directories for you along the file path)

Comment: It just says dict object has no attribute iteritems

Comment: Whopse, in python 3 it's just ``items``